# How to emulate a network with VirtualBox

Tags: routing

I'm trying to emulate a network where there are 2 routers, 3 subnets, and 2 PCs. I've used Debian OS on all the devices, I configured all the IP addresses, but I can't ping from PC-1 (subnet 1) to PC-2 (subnet 3). I suppose that I have to install quagga and configure OSPF on the router's interfaces. Do you have some references to emulate this network properly?

Comment: Linux does not require additional software for regular routing. Did you enable routing?

Comment: To communicate to another subnet the quagga software is required

Comment: No, it is not. There is exactly one thing required: Enabling routing. If the target subnet is behind another hop, a route is also needed.

Comment: How many VMs have you setup for this?

Comment: 4 VMs (2 PCs and 2 routers)

Comment: If there are 2 routers, is not enough enabling routing because there are 3 subnets: 1 subnet in the left of the first router, a second subnet between router one and router two and a third subnet in the right of the second router. If you don't use OSPF you have to use something else like the static routing.